# page favicon/title not showing through proxied cloudflare site

Tags: html, proxy, cloudflare, namecheap

So I recently bought a domain on namecheap for a minecraft server I have. Everything was working fine except for that I didn't have ssl on the website so it was showing as insecure. I changed the nameservers to the ones cloudflare provides for me, and it's proxying requests through cloudflare with encryption, so the security problem is fixed. The actual site is hosted on a github site, and on the github.io site itself, the favicon and title work just fine, but through the proxy, the icon just shows as a little grey globe icon and the title is the link of the site (https://tesseractmc.com). Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Saw your website. Favicon is not visible on  **https://tesseractmc.com** because it is using an iframe which has the src attribute equal to the github page.

What you are really doing is just copying and displaying the content of the github page in the body element of the **https://tesseractmc.com** page.

See Image below

[image]

In the source code for the website, there is not favicon image provided.

Therefore, favicon is not visible.

Comment: So how can I actually fix this issue? I'd appreciate anything that works.

Comment: In the actual github code, there is a favicon provided, but when viewing the source code via the website, it shows that there isn't.

Comment: The issue is just because you're using an IFrame. One possible solution is add the favicon directly in the main website (https://tesseractmc.com) by providing the link to the image -> <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="URL_TO_FAVICON"/>