# page favicon/title not showing through site proxied through cloudflare

Tags: html, proxy, cloudflare, namecheap

I recently bought a domain on namecheap for a minecraft server I have. Everything was working fine except for that I didn't have ssl on the website so it was showing as insecure. I changed the nameservers to the ones cloudflare provides for me, and it's proxying requests through cloudflare with encryption, so the security problem is fixed. The actual site is hosted on a github site, and on the github.io site itself, the favicon and title work just fine, but through the proxy, the icon just shows as a little grey globe icon and the title is the link of the site (https://tesseractmc.com/). A friend told me that the favicon is not visible because my site is using an iframe which has the src attribute equal to the github page so what i'm really doing is copying and displaying the content of the github page in the body element of the site. In the github code, there is a favicon that I provided, but when viewing the source, it shows that it's not provided. Does anyone know how I can change the favicon and page title? I can send screenshots of the cloudflare records if that would help.

Comment: This site is for problems with programming, I'm sure you question is better suited on Server Fault.

Comment: Also, do not post the same question twice. Combine the questions and delete one of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508719/page-favicon-title-not-showing-through-proxied-cloudflare-site